# Why OracleBulkCopy not available in Oracle.ManagedDataAccess?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I am using `OracleManagedDataAccess` in one of my projects and was looking to use `OracleBulkCopy`. But I couldn't find it in `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client` Namespace. Why is it missing?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is a duplicate. Please flag.